# Is there a simple reason for why the two stationary points in a cubic polynomial has its second derivative equal in magnitude but opposite in sign.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials, cubics

Given a polynomial $f(x) = x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c$, then
$$f'(x) = 3x^2 + 2ax + b$$
$$f''(x) = 6x + 2a$$
The stationary points in the curve will have $x = \frac{-a \pm \sqrt{a^2 - 3b}}{6}$, but then the two points have their second derivative equal in magnitude but opposite in sign since
$$f''(\frac{-a + \sqrt{a^2 - 3b}}{3}) = \sqrt{a^2 - 3b} = -f''(\frac{-a - \sqrt{a^2 - 3b}}{3})$$
I remembered that I once had an intuition why this is true but I forgot now. Could somebody tell me why? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you translate the graph so that the single point of inflection is the origin then the resulting function is odd.

Comment: oh right, the point of inflection has its x-coordinate being $-\frac{a}{3}$, when we replace $x$ with $x + \frac{a}{3}$, then the even-indexed term vanishes.

Comment: just out of curiosity, was this what you meant to say?

Comment: @LearningMathematics That's both more and less than what I meant. More because it does some of the algebra, less because I wanted to focus on the symmetry in the geometry.

Comment: How do you know that a cubic curve is symmetrical about its inflection point in the geometry?

Comment: @LearningMathematics You do the algebra. The horizontal and vertical translations remove both the even order terms. I agree that's a nonanswer to the intended question in your comment. But if you've looked at the graphs of a few cubics you can predict that the algebra will work out.

Comment: @LearningMathematics  If you're still interested, I just did the algebraic part for a related question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3823142/prove-if-fx-ax3bx2cxd-has-two-critical-numbers-their-average-is-the-ab/4228725#4228725